# Выбор каркаса RIA (Rich Internet Application)

Tags: каркас

Добрый день!

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие самые популярные, функциональные и удобные **OpenSource FrameWork** для создания **Rich Internet Application**? Меня интересуют чтобы в них были различные компоненты, например, таблица данных, форма и другие.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [статье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_Application---) из Википедии, наиболее распространенные платформы для RIA

- Adobe Flash,
- Oracle JavaFX
- Microsoft Silverlight

Но сказать про них, что это платформы с открытым кодом, я бы затруднился.

Лично я могу посоветовать посмотреть в сторону [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) для простых веб-приложений и в сторону [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/) для сложных приложений. И то, и то популярно, функционально, удобно и с открытым кодом. В JQuery UI скрипты пишутся на JavaScript, а в GWT приложение пишется на Java, а потом компилируется в JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение активно использует БД, я бы использовал библиотеку [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).